# Is there a better expression for "not all roses"?

Tags: expressions, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a better expression for "not all roses"?
"Not all roses" sounds a bit cliched. This is for my personal history statement.

Eg: Once the design was complete, I thought the experiments would go smooth. Contrary to my expectation, the next step was ____________________ (not all roses).

Comment: "... would go *smoothly*..."

Comment: "not all roses" might be replaced with something like "challenging." Or difficult--or synonyms.  What's a personal history--what is it for?

Comment: For a PhD application. I need to write about my experience from working at laboratories.

Comment: @Explorer , this is incredibly important context. Idioms like this may be a bit too informal for a PhD application. I know this was years ago, but some others may benefit from this.

Answer (score 1):

To keep parallelism with the previous sentence, "rough going."

Comment: The sentence can be tweaked if you have a better expression.

Comment: @Explorer I think "Once the design was complete, I thought the experiments would go **smoothly**. Contrary to my **expectations**, the next step was **rough going**." is fine.  "My expectations" is always plural for some reason.

Comment: These don't carry the same meaning as "not all roses". "Not all roses" suggests that there may have been some positive but it certainly wasn't all positive/easy/nice, e.g. "relationships can be wonderful, but they're definitely not all roses", meaning they can be hard work. "Rough going" suggests that it was not easy at all, maybe even that it was a slog. This may be what you wanted but it's not the same thing as what you asked for alternatives to.